# Как при сериализации изменить имя POJO?

Tags: android, retrofit

использую библиотеку retrofit. получаю такой json

```
{
    {
        "fixture":
        {
            "id": 149461,
            "competitionId": 406,
            "date": "2014-07-08T20:00:00Z",
            "matchday": 6,
            "homeTeamName": "Brazil",
            "homeTeamId": 764,
            "awayTeamName": "Germany",
            "awayTeamId": 759,
            "result":
            {
                "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
                "goalsAwayTeam": 7
            }
        },
        "head2head":
        {
            "count": 2,
            "timeFrameStart": "2002-06-30",
            "timeFrameEnd": "2014-07-08",
            "homeTeamWins": 1,
            "awayTeamWins": 1,
            "draws": 0,
            "lastHomeWinHomeTeam": null,
            "lastWinHomeTeam":
            {
                "id": 141629,
                "competitionId": 367,
                "date": "2002-06-29T22:00:00Z",
                "matchday": 8,
                "homeTeamName": "Germany",
                "homeTeamId": 759,
                "awayTeamName": "Brazil",
                "awayTeamId": 764,
                "result":
                {
                    "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
                    "goalsAwayTeam": 2
                }
            },
            "lastAwayWinAwayTeam":
            {
                "id": 149461,
                "competitionId": 406,
                "date": "2014-07-08T20:00:00Z",
                "matchday": 6,
                "homeTeamName": "Brazil",
                "homeTeamId": 764,
                "awayTeamName": "Germany",
                "awayTeamId": 759,
                "result":
                {
                    "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
                    "goalsAwayTeam": 7
                }
            },
            "lastWinAwayTeam":
            {
                "id": 149461,
                "competitionId": 406,
                "date": "2014-07-08T20:00:00Z",
                "matchday": 6,
                "homeTeamName": "Brazil",
                "homeTeamId": 764,
                "awayTeamName": "Germany",
                "awayTeamId": 759,
                "result":
                {
                    "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
                    "goalsAwayTeam": 7
                }
            },
            "fixtures":
            [
                {
                    "id": 149461,
                    "competitionId": 406,
                    "date": "2014-07-08T20:00:00Z",
                    "matchday": 6,
                    "homeTeamName": "Brazil",
                    "homeTeamId": 764,
                    "awayTeamName": "Germany",
                    "awayTeamId": 759,
                    "result":
                    {
                        "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
                        "goalsAwayTeam": 7
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 141629,
                    "competitionId": 367,
                    "date": "2002-06-29T22:00:00Z",
                    "matchday": 8,
                    "homeTeamName": "Germany",
                    "homeTeamId": 759,
                    "awayTeamName": "Brazil",
                    "awayTeamId": 764,
                    "result":
                    {
                        "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
                        "goalsAwayTeam": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

И в моем проекте есть такой класс

```
public class Event 
{

   @SerializedName("id")
   @Expose
   private Integer id;
   @SerializedName("competitionId")
   @Expose
   private Integer competitionId;
   //.....
 }
```

То есть все поля моего класса Event соответствуют вложенному в "head2head" "fixtures", что в ответе JSON.
(отличается только имя класса)
Мне нужны только данные из этого "fixtures".
Как правильно проаннотировать класс Event (если так вообще возможно) чтобы можно было использовать его для парсинга такого ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам проще будет не использовать автоматическую сериализацию ретрофита, а получать от него response в виде JSON, выдергивать нужные структуры и их уже сериализировать в POJO.

Иначе придется либо писать кастомную сериализацию, либо всю структуру ответа описать в виде POJO.

Comment: Gson умеет отсекать неуказанные поля при парсинге, а писать свой сериализатор как раз таки будет дольше мне кажется

Comment: @SviatVolkov, он умеет, но это же не освобождает от построения структуры ответа в виде POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда, если я правильно понял, нужно выкинуть Конвертер с билдера.
получим что то вроде:

```
 mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.football-data.org")
            .build();
```

,а возвращать Response?

```
@GET("/v1/fixtures/{matchId}")
    Observable<Response> getEvents(@Query("matchId") int matchId);
```

В активити я пишу:

```
observable = App.getAPIJson().getEvents(159316); // Exception in this line!
        observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "JSON, onCompleted");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "SOMETHING WRONG WITH JSON: " + e.getMessage().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, response.body().toString());
                    }
                });
```

и получаю Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable

Не нашел ни одного примера, где использовали бы retrofit без десериализации в POJO. Подскажите, может возвращаемый тип не тот применил?

Comment: Если хотите получить JSON от ретрофита, то `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` надо в билдер добавить.

Comment: Соответственно и ответ API будет типа `Observable<JsonObject>`